# Identifying similar records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am doing a cleanup of a customer table. The customer table receives data from 4 different sources and there are many duplicate records. I am using a combination of rules to identify similar customer records. The rule I have are:

1. they have same firstname,lastname, email and mobile
2. they have similar lastname, mobile and email
3. they have similar firstname, lastname and email.

I want to assign them a new unique_id like the output below:

[image: expected output]

Here is the code for the table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.customer(
customer_id int,
first_name varchar(100),
last_name varchar(100),
email varchar(100),
mobile varchar(20),
unique_id int)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.customer(customer_id, first_name, last_name, email, mobile)
values (5475872,'','SMITH','john.smith@fakeemail.com','123456'),
(623073,'JOHN','SMITH','john.smith@fakeemail.com','123456'),
(1286681,'JOHN','SMITH','john.smith@fakeemail.com','123456'),
(1303103,'JOHN','SMITH','john.smith@fakeemail.com','123456'),
(7063902,'JOHN','SMITH','john.smith@fakeemail.com','987654'),
(1808155,'JOHN','SMITH','john.smith@fakeemail.com','123456'),
(2151985,'','SMITH','john.smith@fakeemail.com','123456'),
(7221764,'JOHN','SMITH','john.smith@fakeemail.com','987654'),
(1870704,'JOHN','','john.smith@fakeemail.com','123456'),
(887842,'BILL','GATES','bill@microsoft.com','555555'),
(736363,'','GATES','bill@microsoft.com','555555')
GO
```

Can anyone help me on how I can generate that unique_id column based on different combinations?

Thanks

Comment: The hardest part of what you are trying to do is going to be defining what you mean by "similar"

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14760/best-way-to-compare-strings-using-pre-built-ngrams

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore rules 2 and 3 for the moment, because the terms "similar" first name and "similar" last name are not well defined enough to implement.  If we just use rule 1 to de-duplicate, we can do this:

```
WITH unique_id_query AS(
    SELECT first_name, 
           last_name, 
           email, 
           mobile, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY last_name, first_name, email, mobile) AS unique_id
    FROM dbo.customer
    GROUP BY first_name, last_name, email, mobile
)
UPDATE customer
SET unique_id = unique_id_query.unique_id
FROM dbo.customer
JOIN unique_id_query ON customer.first_name=unique_id_query.first_name
                    AND customer.last_name =unique_id_query.last_name
                    AND customer.email     =unique_id_query.email
                    AND customer.mobile    =unique_id_query.mobile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the duplicate records using the below code as email appears to be unique and common in your all search criterias. Use in Update  by joining with Customer_id and then select the result.

```
 UPDATE C 
 SET C.unique_id =  B.Unique_id
 FROM 
 customer AS C 
    INNER JOIN 
     ( Select 
       DENSE_rank() over ( order by  email desc) AS Unique_id  
       ,customer_id
        from customer 
     )  AS B on  C.customer_id = B.customer_id

  SELECT *  FROM dbo.customer
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @user2654992 Let me know if further help required. Happy to assist :)